# Resizing a storyboard uitableview programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize

Because of apple's new rule change that require apps to be iPhone 5 compatible, I have to now make my UItableview (in viewcontrollers, not tableviewcontrollers) resize properly. However, sometimes they do not, especially when they are in the middle of the controller. Is there a way to just programmatically dictate it's new size limit without having to get rid of my storyboard layout such as with...

```
tableFrame.size.height = 127
```

or

```
CGRect schedulesNewFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                      _movieSynopsis.frame.origin.y + _movieSynopsis.frame.size.height + 4,
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                      self.tableView.contentSize.height);

    [self.tableView setFrame: schedulesNewFrame];
```

**Update**
To clarify my question a little better, when it does autoresize, sometimes it doesn't do it properly. Is there any way to manually control this while keeping my storyboard for normal iPhones?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: And then...I just use tableFrame.size.height = 127?

Comment: Nope. Just don't assign the table view a specific height. Make it how you want it to look in IB, then it *should* automatically resize itself.

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have been a little clearer in my question. Sorry. When it does autoresize, sometimes it doesn't do it properly. Is there any way to manually control this while keeping my storyboard for normal iPhones?

Comment: @KevinPuntney Define 'doesn't do it properly'. What does it to, and under what conditions?

Comment: When the UItableview is close to the middle and there are numerous other buttons around it, sometimes it only pulls the table down half way towards where it should be stretching to on the iPhone 5, leaving a bunch of empty space that should not be there

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: So is there a way to manually control the height? I couldn't find anything on it?

Comment: @KevinPuntney, are you using auto layout?